# Latex: Using variable in sub file when defined in main file

Tags: latex

How can I use a variable in the subfile which is defined in the main file?

In the main.tex i include some other files (e. g. the style definitions) as well as I write the revision control and I define a version variable:

```
main.tex

\usepackage{mystyles}
\begin{versionhistory}
  \vhEntry{1.0}{1.1.2011}{abc}{Initial draft}
  % allways update the value of the version variable!
  \newcommand{\docVersion}{1.5}
\end{versionhistory}
```

the style file includes:

```
mystyles.sty

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % better control of header and footer
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{} % clear default header/footer format
\lfoot{\fancyplain{\thepage \docVersion}{\thepage \docVersion}}
```

But this does not work. If i define the docVersion variable in mystyles.sty it works fine, but I don't want to modify mystyles.sty when changing the history of the document. So how can I define a variable in main.tex and using it in the subfile?

Thank
Mark

Comment: No, I did only define the variable in the way mentioned above. I don't know how to declare a variable. Since the `\newcommand` asks for two Argument, I can't declare it by `\newcommand{\varname}`

Comment: Ahh, the problem was, I defined it within the versionhistory block. Outside of that block it works (no matter if it's at the beginning of main.tex, before or after `\usepackage{mystyles}`, which uses the variable.

Comment: Thx for Inspiration ;)

Answer (score 1):

The error was the position of the `\newcommand`command. It must not be inbetween a versionhistory block. So the following works:

main.tex:

```
\usepackage{mystyles}
\newcommand{\docVersion}{1.5}
\begin{versionhistory}
  \vhEntry{1.0}{1.1.2011}{abc}{Initial draft}
  % allways update the value of the docVersion variable above!
\end{versionhistory}
```

and mystyles.sty

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % better control of header and footer
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{} % clear default header/footer format
\lfoot{\fancyplain{\thepage \docVersion}{\thepage \docVersion}}
```